# NDK - Build ARMv5/ARMv7 shared libraries from static ones

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I have two static libraries that I built from a specified project.

```
ARMv5 / myLib.a
ARMv7 / myLib.a
```

Now, I want to use those libraries and build two shared library for ARMv5 and ARMV7 platforms.

Is there a way to specify the fact that I want to use two versions of my static library ?
For now, I'm doing a bad trick in my ANT Script which just consists in:

1. Copy the static ARMv5 library.
2. Build the shared library (**ARMv5**).
3. Delete ARMv5 static lib and copy ARMv7 version.
4. Build again a shared library (**ARMv7**).

I know there is

```
"APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a"
```

but how to tell him that I want to build from two separated static lib and not just from one?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not be the best approach but, you can try using if else statements in your Android.mk and check for APP_ABI values and use the corresponding libraries.

```
ifeq ($(APP_ABI), armeabi-v7a)
  LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ARMv7/myLib.a
else
  LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ARMv5/myLib.a
endif
```

Or use LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES in case you directly link them. Of course, your Application.mk should include the line that you stated:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a
```

Comment: In fact, I do not have a static library anymore but building all my sources in a shared library for ARMv5/v7. However, I get a lot of "multiple definition of..." during the build. Any idea ?

Comment: Difficult to tell without having to see the current structure of your implementation but definetely you include or define one member in multiple places. I tested my solution and it would solve your problem if you sticked to using static libraries. Anyway, your current problem is a matter of another question I suppose.

Comment: Yep, I posted another question because it's totally different from this one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187853/ndk-android-cant-build-armv5-and-v7-at-the-same-time). Thank you for your help by the way !