# NDK Android - Can't build ARMv5 and V7 at the same time

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I'm facing a weird problem.
I'm building a shared library for my Android application.

I can't build both armv5 and armv7 at the same time.
If I do so, I get a lot of errors on my source files at the second run (when the ndk build the armV7 lib) like:

```
FinderPatternInfo.o: previous definition here
multiple definition of ...
```

My **Application.mk**

```
APP_ABI             := armeabi armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM        := android-8
APP_STL             := stlport_static
APP_CPPFLAGS        += -fexceptions
```

It works perfectly if I only set APP_ABI := armeabi or APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a..

Any idea ?
Thank you for your help,

EDIT: Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE            := MyModule

MY_LOCAL_INCLUDED_FILES += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*.h)
MY_LOCAL_INCLUDED_FILES += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*.hpp)
MY_LOCAL_INCLUDED_FILES += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/bigint/*.h)
... (many includes)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES        :=  $(subst jni/, , $(MY_LOCAL_INCLUDED_FILES))

MY_LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*.c)
MY_LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*.cpp)
MY_LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/bigint/*.c)
.... (many cpp files)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES     :=  $(subst jni/, , $(MY_LOCAL_SRC_FILES))

LOCAL_CFLAGS        := -DNO_ICONV

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Do you get two separate folders in your libs or obj folder like armeabi and armeabi-v7a?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure, but it should be automatic right ? I tried to do "ndk-build clean" but nothing changed.
At the beginning of the process, I also get a lot of errors like:
"warning: overriding commands for target" // "warning: ignoring old commands for target"

Comment: In default case, armeabi and armeabi-v7a outputs are separated into their respective folders as you might expect. If your output folders are the same for both architectures, then you might expect that error since it is already defined from the previous build. I don't know why that default behaviour should be broken but it seems like the case. You can try using NDK_APP_OUT := /path/to/armeabi and NDK_APP_OUT := path/to/armeabi-v7a inside proper if else statements in your Application.mk if you are sure that your libs folder does not contain armeabi and armeabi-v7a folders.

Comment: Well, at the first run there is a library which is copied into "project\libs\armeabi", but the second time it fails because of multiple definitions. It's weird, at the beginning of the process I get error like " [exec] C:/Developer/androidndk/android-ndk-r8e/build/core/build-binary.mk:269: warning: overriding commands for target `C:\Developer\androidndk\android-ndk-r8e/apps/ProjectName/project/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/MyModule/aes_modes.o'" , like it's looking directly for armv7... I tried reinstalling the ndk but nothing changed.

Comment: "`warning: overriding commands for target `xxx''
`warning: ignoring old commands for target `xxx''
    GNU make allows commands to be specified only once per target (except for double-colon rules). If you give commands for a target which already has been defined to have commands, this warning is issued and the second set of commands will overwrite the first set." 



Maybe you should post your Android.mk. Seems like there is a duplication somewhere but I am not sure that's the source of the problem.

Comment: Posted Android.mk in first post.

Comment: Why do you try to include every file by giving out their specific names? Just including the directory should be enough. For example, if all your headers reside in Headers directory, giving LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := path/to/Headers is sufficient instead of giving whole .h or .hpp files.

Comment: Well, .h and .cpp are in the same directories and my project contains a lot of sub directories. We already investigated on this, we do not have the choice, we must list all sub directories. If we don't, it will not recognize include like <myDir/subDir/myInclude.h>
I dont think the problem comes from here.

Comment: Sorry to insist, but there is something wrong here. If you specify an include directory, all subdirectories are included along with it. If your header file resides in myDir/subDir, including myDir is sufficient if you use the header as #include <subDir/myInclude.h>. I guess the duplication error comes from this, you try to include a header file that you already included by specifying the upper directory. Again, including the directory is enough, you don't have to go through each header file in that directory.

Comment: Well, I just included the main directory as you suggested. It still works well but I also still get the error above... Don't know what to do now.

Answer (score 3):

The Android make system parses your Android.mk once for each target, so your **MY_LOCAL_SRC_FILES** gets a full set of all of your .c and .cpp files twice when there are two targets, but only one of each when there's a single target.

If your first **MY_LOCAL_SRC_FILES** assignment used := instead of +=, I think it would fix the problem.